# In the SO Moderator Primary Election, why are some counts of down-votes positive and others negative

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, election

I was idly looking at the number of up and down vote counts on the SO Moderator primary election pages, and realized some of the down-vote scores were positive, and others negative, which is … puzzling.

I'm not sure what reputation you need to see the effect; it's when you click on the total score you can (if you have enough reputation, I assume) see the breakdown.

[image: Positive down-votes]    [image: Negative down-votes]

Sorry about the misalignment — manual snapping of the images.

Is this a bug? Is there a good explanation?

Comment: Obviously one of them had a negative number of downvotes! ;)

Comment: I think it would be more sensible if both numbers were positive and the difference was what got displayed as negative.  But I agree that this is a duplicate of the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer:

Both of them have a negative sign in front of them

You just don't see the negative sign on the first one since it's 3 characters long , so it gets hidden from view since the width isn't wide enough.

Comment: Not quite true. It's not hidden from view because of the width, it's completely removed from the number server-side. If you made the box wider it still wouldn't be there.